# Get the path dynamically of the xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this and I want the attribute which is defined in the "title" using XSL file.

I want to retrieve the value even if I change the elements

- catalog with books
- cd with book

XML:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title att="abce"  att2="false">Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I tried this method to get att value

```
<xsl:variable name="outermostElementName" select="catalog/cd/title/attribute::att"/>
```

but this is specific to this XML only I want it to be genric

Is there any way?

Comment: Librak: You may be interested to see a more generic, true XSLT solution than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current **xsl:variable**, I think you could use one of the following to more generic

```
<xsl:variable name="outermostElementName" select="catalog/*/title/@att" />
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="outermostElementName" select="//title/@att" />
```

The first one assumes the root element is always called **catalog**. The second one does not depend on an ancestor nodes, but will pick up the **title** element at any level in the XML.

Comment: yes it is helpful but what if there is no catalog,cd and title 
i meanit is books,book and title...??
is there any method to detect this...

Answer (score 0):

**The genericity you want to achieve is offered by the XSLT template match patterns**.

You can simply have:

```
<xsl:template match="title/@att">
  <!-- Your processing here  -->
</xsl:template>
```

and whenever there is an `<xsl:apply-templates select="expression"/>` instruction such that `expression` selects a `title/@att` attribute, the template above will be selected for ptocessing of this attribute node.

**This doesn't depend on any other outside context.**